# Count null and non-null values in all columns in a table

Tags: sql, count, null

I have a table with two column like below:

```
name         marks
  A            15
  B            
  c            20
```

As is clear from above, column `name` has 3 non-null values and 1 null value, similarly column `marks` has 2 null as well 2 non-null values.

What's the query to get this result?

Comment: `count(columnname)` counts only non-null values. `count(*)` counts all rows. Now you do the math!

Comment: i want to count columnwise null and non null records present in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this -

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS name_not_null_count, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS name_null_count
FROM table
```

Approach to calculate null count is: mark all the null records with 1 and take  `SUM`.

Answer (score 1):

`count(columnname)` counts only non-null values. `count(*)` counts all rows.

```
select count(name) as names,
       count(*) - count(name) as null_names,
       count(marks) as marks,
       count(*) - count(marks) as null_marks
from tablenam
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS name_count, COUNT(marks) AS marks_count FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select number of rows, number of rows with null, and number of rows with non-null value. Repeat the select for each desired column.

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmp
 (
     i int
 )

 INSERT INTO #tmp values(1)
 INSERT INTO #tmp values(2)
 INSERT INTO #tmp values(3)
 INSERT INTO #tmp values(NULL)

 SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num_Rows
  , COUNT(i) AS Num_Not_Null
  , COUNT(*)-COUNT(i) AS Num_Null 
 FROM #tmp
```

Num_Rows    Num_Not_Null Num_Null

---

4           3            1